# Grandlew bat file not found in windows 10

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

[image]
[image]I have installed flutter and android studio. Followed some resources I have added path.(In windows)

But everytime I run the first project it is giving errors 
like. Grandlew bat file not found.

sometimes : exception: exit with 1

Flutter doctor is always giving licenses unknown. I tried number of solutions in the YouTube and from here..but still getting same thing..
My dreams are going to stop in the first step.

[image: For every new flutter run command it is giving diff errors]

[image]
[image: If I execute again flutter run then it will show gradlew script error]

Answer (score 0):

you need to install flutter and dart plugin in your android studio/VS code.

to install a plugin in Android Studio follow these steps

- Launch Android Studio application
- Choose File -> Settings (For Mac Preference )
- Search for Flutter then for dart(But dart will be installed automatically with flutter)

I just noticed you don't have Android SDK either, for that, you should go to your android studio and on the top right corner click on the SDK icon, and then install 28/29 version of android SDK hopefully it will solve your problem

alternatively, you can download SDK from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) as well

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already installed android sdk. You can observe that in the above attachments. Android version 4.0 is installed but again it showing like that.

Comment: Number of times I completely uninstalled android studio and installed with the proper sdk path and full of sdk tools available in SDK manager -> SDK tools -> (all plugins recommended for SDK)

Comment: you have installed Android Studio (4.0 is version of your android Studio, not android SDK) Android SDK is something entirely different, your error shows that android studio/flutter can't locate android sdk, so if you could then provide the path manually in sdk manager menu in tools.

Comment: I installed sdk (which consists of tools,platforms,platform-tools folders) in some other folder and mentioned that path in env and also I have checked sdk manager path under tool in astudio..the path is same as SDK.

Comment: and have you configured that path in your environment variables of your PC?

Comment: I have added some attachments of my environment path. Can you please find that ?